# App Registration in Azure AD disappear after about 2 weeks and appear in Enterprise Apps

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have an app (its actually the Audit Logs custom connector for the PowerPlatform Center of Excellence package) which about 2 weeks after I register it in App Registrations migrates to Enterprise Apps and I can no longer use the Custom Connector because the system cannot find it in App Registrations.  I re-register the custom connector and it all works for a couple of weeks before it disappears again.

Anybody got any odeas why this is happening ?

Thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this will not happen, as long as you register the app in Azure AD App registrations, it will definitely not disappear suddenly unless you delete it.

You need to make sure that the account you log in is the account that created the application, or when you log in with other account under the **same tenant**, use **All applications** to find the name of the application.

[image]